# Ubuntu 20.04 Files, Connect to server is missing

Tags: server, 20.04, files

In my Ubuntu 20.04 Files I have no option "Connect to server".

Comment: Doesn't it show up when you choose "Other locations" (from the left side bar), then at the very bottom of that screen?